# Char type not taking an input

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

For some reason I can not write to the ch char type from the scanf_s I am using in visual studio 2013  I have tried spacing the "%c" both ways " %c" and tried scanf and scanf_s.  I am lost.

```
// Alphabetic Pyramid Program - The Egyptians must have used C!
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    printf("Enter the letter that will be the foundations of your Aphabetic Pyramid:\n");  // User is promted to enter a letter
    scanf_s(" %c", &ch);   // User inputs Foundational_letter
    printf("The code for %c is %d!\n", ch, ch);

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Please remember: C and C++ are not the same language. Only tag one. Also, with `scanf_s` I believe you need to provide the sizeof the buffer: `scanf_s(" %c", &ch, 1);`

Comment: "I can not write to the ch char type from the scan_f". Please be more specific. Is there an error?  If there is incorrect behaviour then please provide the input, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 4):

scanf_s expects two arguments for the `%c` specifier: the receiving address and the size, which is 1:

```
scanf_s(" %c", &ch, 1);
```

By design, all safe versions of scanf (those ending with `_s`) need some parameter specifying how much buffer space you reserved for receiving the input when it is of types string (%s) and char (%c). i.e. for `%s` you would specify the buffer address and its reserved size.

If you dont apply these rules, expect undefined behavior.

Comment: ["When multiple characters for non-null terminated strings are read, integers are used as the width specification and the buffer size."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx#Anchor_2)